# Mysqldump -x option to escape XML characters

Tags: xml, escaping, mysql

I'm exporting a MySQL database as XML using mysqldump -x. Many of my fields contain apostrophes and other characters which confuse [mysqldump-x-restore](http://code.google.com/p/mysqldump-x-restore/)'s XSLT stylesheet.

It's not sufficient to just run through the file and escape the characters that XML has problems with, as that would replace every legal XML bracket and quote as well. Is there an option somewhere on mysqldump to do XML escaping on column data?

Comment: My `mysqldump` (mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.57, for debian-linux-gnu (i486)), only uses `"` for the xml attributes, and properly encodes those in fields as `&quot;` on `--xml` output (as it does `>` & `<`. It leaves the single quote `'` alone, and if that xsl has problems with that one, that's the  only one you need to alter, which can be done without endangering the XML.

Comment: I'm using 10.13 / 5.1.49. It's weird, I'd swear that I've escaped all my apostrophes, but still this XSLT breaks... Guess its time to raise a bug. If you want to make an answer out of this I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

If only a few special characters results in trouble, you may achieve the same result as mysqldump -x with the execute (-e) option combined with REPLACE functions in the regular mysql client.

Example that escapes the ampersand character:

```
mysql --xml -uusername -p -Ddatabasename -e"SELECT REPLACE(field1, '&', '&nbsp;') AS field1 FROM ymse.dbh_inst" > /path/file.xml
```

If you have to escape multiple special characters this method will lead to ugly nested REPLACE statments since MySQL don't support regexp replace.